# How to define orientation mapping for parametrization of a 1-manifold in a 1 dimensional space

Tags: integration, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Here is a simple example that confuses me regarding the orientation mappings:

In order to compute $\int_4^9{tdt}$ using $t=x^2$ parametrization in the interval $[-2,3]$ (i.e. $\int_{-2}^{3}{2x^3dx}$), one have to first prove that $t=x^2$ is an orientation preserving parametrization in $[-2,3]$. However, at $x=0$, the derivative of parametrization vanishes and orientation mapping inevitably jumps from +1 to -1.

In such a case, how can one prove that $t=x^2$ is an orientation preserving parametrization in intervals containing 0?

Comment: It is not, precisely because the derivative vanish at some point of the interval.

Comment: But the entire 1st year calculus is based on such ridiculous change of parameter rules and for some reason it works. I kind of "believe" that there sould be a sane explanation for that. What if we define orienation function as $\Omega_x(v)=sign(\frac{v}{x})$. In such a case, we can at least define a constant orientation for the parametrization.

Comment: But the definition of orientation preserving (or reversing) requires that the derivative never vanishes.

Comment: An orientation function $\Omega_x$ is also required to be nonzero for every $x$ (it means that $\Omega_x(v)=0\Leftrightarrow v=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have correctly observed, $t=x^2$ is not an orientation preserving parameterization in any interval that contains $0$. The fact that the "change of coordinate" formula actually works in this example is a coincidence. Here's why.

If instead you were to use the interval $[2,3]$ (i.e. $\int_{2}^3 2x^3 \, dx$), then you could, of course, apply the change of parameter rules without trouble, to conclude that
$$\int_4^9 t \, dt = \int_2^3 2x^3 \, dx
$$
Here's the coincidence: $2x^3$ is an odd function, and therefore $\int_{-2}^2 2x^3 \, dx = 0$. It follows that
$$\int_{-2}^3 2 x^3 \, dx = \underbrace{\int_{-2}^2 2 x^3 \, dx}_{=0} + \int_2^3 2x^3 \, dx = \int_2^3 2x^3 \, dx
$$
If you tried to do this in a situation where the change-of-variables integrand was not an odd function, it would not work.